# Create a Calendar that displays one year from today(Asp.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to create a calendar that displays a year from today(everyday) and allows the user to select the multiple dates.

I tried to use the asp:calendar without any success

I am developing in C# .NET

any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great one in JavaScript

http://jquery-week-calendar.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.weekcalendar/full_demo/weekcalendar_full_demo.html